# R dyplr: Get index of column by its name

Tags: r, dplyr

I need to get the index of a column from a `data.table` or `tbl_df` by it's name,

is there an easier way than:

```
getColIndex <- function(df, colnameTarget = "myColumnName") {
    colnames <- names(traindata_subset)
    colIndex <- 1
    found <- FALSE
    for(colname in colnames) {
        if (colname == colnameTarget) {
            found <- TRUE
            break
        }
        colIndex <- colIndex + 1
    }

    if (found) {
        return (colIndex)
    }
    else {
        return (-1)
    }
}
```

Especially using Hadley's `dplyr`?

Comment: AAAHH you beat me to it @David!!

Comment: More amusing way may consider using [**`gather`**](https://rpubs.com/bradleyboehmke/data_wrangling), which plays super well with `dplyr`. Then you will get your column names in a column and you can derive indexes or whatever else you may want.

Comment: @Konrad You could do that with `base` R perhaps, by just doing `data.frame(names(df))`

Comment: @MaxPD True, personally I like the workflow that `dplyr` / `tidyr` syntax generates.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try with `base` R: and first answered by David above:

```
index <- match(colname, names(df))
```

Comment: Im sorry, I didnt see it :(

Comment: I wonder how much time is wasted every day by reimplementing already implemented `R` functions... :)

Answer (score 4):

`which(names(df) == "myColumnName")` is what you're looking for, if I understand your aim correctly?